# How to add a required parameter in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating an authentication page in flutter using [this github repository](https://github.com/abuanwar072/Welcome-Login-Signup-Page-Flutter). I have managed to get rid of most errors. I have a **body.dart** file that imports from other files one of them being **background.dart** that has a constructor with required parameters. Using a widget in **body.dart** brings up the error

```
The named parameter 'key' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.dart(missing_required_argument)
```

These are the code:
**background.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const Background({
    //added required to the key and child
    required Key key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      height: size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/main_top.png",
              width: size.width * 0.3,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/main_bottom.png",
              width: size.width * 0.2,
            ),
          ),
          child,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**body.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:meekap/Screens/Welcome/components/background.dart';
import 'package:meekap/Screens/Login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:meekap/Screens/Signup/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:meekap/components/rounded_button.dart';
import '../../../constants.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // This size provide us total height and width of our screen
    return Background(//Error comes up here
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Welcome to meeKap",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            Image.asset(
              "assets/icons/chat.svg",
              height: size.height * 0.45,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            RoundedButton(//Error comes up here
              text: "LOGIN",
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "SIGN UP",
              color: kPrimaryLightColor,
              textColor: Colors.black,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return SignUpScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Lee3 It was to get rid of an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key should not be `required` unless you have a reason to do so.

Remove `required` on the `key` parameter:

```dart
const Background({
    //added required to the key and child
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: removing required as suggested brings an error.  The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Comment: Thanks. It got rid of the errors. Could you add a link where I can get detailed explanation?

Comment: @davidkihara These are all very important elements of null-safety. https://dart.dev/null-safety